# Default subfolders for dovecot

Tags: dovecot, debian-squeeze, maildir

For new accounts, dovecot only has a single default folder, the inbox.

Is there a way to specify a default set of subfolders, preferably immutable, that exist for each inbox?

Ideally, I want each account to have a Sent, Trash, and Drafts folder, which can all be read/written to, but not renamed or deleted.

In case it is relevant, my dovecot configuration specifies no subfolder prefix, so all user-created subfolders exist at the "root" level of the Maildir, which is the mailbox format I’m using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the autocreate plugin

http://wiki.dovecot.org/Plugins/Autocreate

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I was looking for. I tried playing with `dovecot`'s ACL system, but it didn’t seem to work for me. Fortunately, the no-delete part isn’t a requirement for me, only a nicety which I will live without.